# Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1

Tags: android, database, sqlite, runtime-error

I keep getting this in my logcat every time I run my code and cannot figure out how to fix it.  When I update I get this error, I use similar code when I delete and that works fine. I used breakpoints on the update, it kept on going to the end of the function.  I thought that at startActivityForResult would go to the next page, but it does not.  The exact same code for startActivityForResult worked in another function

Here is the code for update

```
    public void edit_to_report_page(final View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_vehicle, null);
    idNum = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.deleteRecord);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Edit a report")
            .setMessage("Enter the Id number of the report to edit")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("Edit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            String id = idNum.getText().toString();
                            uniqueID = Long.parseLong(id);
                            newID(uniqueID);
                            info.open();

                            try {
                                boolean correctNumber = info
                                        .Exists(uniqueID);
                                if (!correctNumber) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Number not found",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    info.close();

                                }else{

                                    info.close();
                                    intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                            report.class);
                                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).show();

}
```

Here is the code for delete that works

```
public void delete_db(View v) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View addView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_vehicle, null);
    idNum = (EditText) addView.findViewById(R.id.deleteRecord);
    final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Delete a report")
            .setMessage("Enter the Id number of the report to delete")
            .setView(addView)
            .setPositiveButton("Delete",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            String id = idNum.getText().toString();
                            long primaryId = Long.parseLong(id);
                            info.open();
                            try {
                                boolean inCorrectNumber = info
                                        .deleteInspection(primaryId);
                                if (inCorrectNumber) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Number not found",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            info.close();
                            dbInfo();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    }).show();
}
```

Here is the code in my dbAdapter for delete and Exists(update)

```
public boolean Exists(long _id)throws Exception
{

    Cursor c = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID},
            "_id=" + _id, null, null, null, null);
     boolean exists=(c.getCount()>0);
    c.close();
    return exists;
}

public boolean deleteInspection(long _id)throws Exception
{
    int numResults = 0;
    numResults = db.delete(DB_TABLE,"_id=" + _id , null);
    return (numResults < 1);
}
```

Here is what I get in logcat

```
04-10 09:47:05.006: E/CursorWindow(2961): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 1
04-10 09:47:05.016: D/AndroidRuntime(2961): Shutting down VM
04-10 09:47:05.027: W/dalvikvm(2961): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.signalsetapp/com.signalsetapp.inspectionchecklist.report}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.signalsetapp.inspectionchecklist.report.getInfoFromDB(report.java:129)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at com.signalsetapp.inspectionchecklist.report.onCreate(report.java:111)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-10 09:47:05.046: E/AndroidRuntime(2961):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You might want to point out what line is causing you this problem.

Comment: I am not 100%.  I used breakpoints and it kept on going to the end of the function.  StartActivity did not go to the next page, however the same code for StartActivity was used in the add function and that worked fine

Comment: looks like "report.java:129" is the bad guy here, is that you code ? If so, could you mark it in the in-lined code above. Should help a bit with debugging this :D

Comment: Thanks, I was changing my code and I changed something I should not have.

Comment: add an answer so I get mark you as the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad to help, 
adding so you can mark as answer :)

looks like "report.java:129" is the bad guy here, is that you code ? If so, could you mark it in the in-lined code above. Should help a bit with debugging this :D – erbsman 4 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

Aaron i have same Exception and solution is `Check your column name you want to access it from cursor is same name as exists in database` .And also remove `white space` and first try to query in `SQLITE browser` And then try in coding and Make some `Debugging ,I mean print query in logcat and copy ,and paste and sqlite Browser` thats a key for you otherwise it take more time and difficulty to solve it!